# access 2013 create a search box on web form using macros

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a macro to filter/search my database tables. I am using a web form and for the macro I am using setfilter. So far I have my where condition as " " & [txtBox] & " " but when I try to search, the button does not work. Can anyone point me into the right direction for the correct way to create a search box macro using access web forms?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using setlocalvar and setfilter macro.

```
SetLocalVar
  Name strName
  Expression = [txtSearch]
SetFilter
  Where Condition = [Field Name] = [LocalVars]![strName]
  Control Name  datasheetName
```